# Android, Standard way to exchange files with PC

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app.

I want to save my app's data, and view or modify in PC also can load from PC. Moreover, want to prevent delete those even though app uninstalling.

So I can't use [internal directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that provided by android standard, because it deleting when uninstalling app and can't see in PC at all.(Except ADT)

And [external public directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) also android standart but can't use, because it is not appear in some models of android devices when connect with PC by USB.(EX. Pantech VEGA R3, My test device)

Additionally, SD card is also there but, somebody do not use SD card, so it can't use as well.(My test device has no SD card, too)

Is there any way for this problem?

Thanks.